# SQL case expression not working correctly in grafana

Tags: sql

I am having trouble getting my sql case expression to work. When i use this sql statement it works fine:

```
  SELECT
    TimeInt AS time,
    oV101DirectionA,
    oV101DirectionB,
    id
  FROM
    machine_data
  WHERE
    id%1=0 AND
    machine_id = 3 AND
    $__unixEpochFilter(TimeInt) = TRUE
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(TimeStr, '%Y%m%d%k%i')
  ORDER BY TimeInt ASC
```

But when i modify the code to scale better then no data is shown neither is a error. When the time window in seconds between two dates is to far apart then it should skip rows in the database for better performance.

```
  SELECT
    TimeInt AS time,
    oV101DirectionA,
    oV101DirectionB,
    id
  FROM
    machine_data
  WHERE
    CASE WHEN ($__unixEpochTo(TimeInt)-$__unixEpochFrom(TimeInt)) > 100 THEN 'id%10 = 0'
        WHEN ($__unixEpochTo(TimeInt)-$__unixEpochFrom(TimeInt)) > 1000 THEN 'id%100 = 0'
    ELSE 'id%1 = 0'
    END AND
    machine_id = 3 AND
    $__unixEpochFilter(TimeInt) = TRUE
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(TimeStr, '%Y%m%d%k%i')
  ORDER BY TimeInt ASC
```

I've read alot online about case statements within sql but couldn't find a answer for my specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is what you want:

```
WHERE ( ( $__unixEpochTo(TimeInt) - $__unixEpochFrom(TimeInt) > 100 AND
         (id % 10) = 0
        ) OR
        ( $__unixEpochTo(TimeInt) - $__unixEpochFrom(TimeInt) > 1000 AND
          (id % 1000 = 0
        ) OR
        COALESCE($__unixEpochTo(TimeInt) - $__unixEpochFrom(TimeInt), 0) <= 100)
      ) AND
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `CASE` expression in this way, because it's output is a *value*, not a logical condition.  But we can reword your `WHERE` logic to this:

```
WHERE
    (($__unixEpochTo(TimeInt) - $__unixEpochFrom(TimeInt) > 100 AND id%10 = 0) OR
     ($__unixEpochTo(TimeInt) - $__unixEpochFrom(TimeInt)) > 1000 AND id%100 = 0) OR
    id%1 = 0) AND
    machine_id = 3 AND
    $__unixEpochFilter(TimeInt) = TRUE
```